# Route web Node.js + Vagrant + Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, vagrant

I have 3 instances of CoreOS in Vagrant. In one of them I have a Docker container with Node.js and other with MongoDB. The Node.js container has nginx configured and working if I do a wget in the container and in the instance of coreOS. My question is if I have to configure something more to show the website in my navigator, because I can´t.

May I have to put a router or something else in Vagrant?

Comment: we'd probably need Vagrantfile and what exactly you try from your navigator (do you have private network or only forward port enabled ?) to be able to help. also if you have forward port, try with localhost:8080 or 8000 ? and not 127.0.0.1, this is a common issue

Comment: I fixed it. I have to config the input and output port when I ran the docker container with -p 80:80. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to point out that you should apply seperation of concern, and split out nginx and node in seperate containers each responsible for their own tasks.

That would leave you with a nginx container, a node container and a mongodb container which you will then need to link. This can be done in multiple ways. One of them is to bind the port the container is exposing to either the hosts private or public IP address, and a port on that address.

That, in a normal CoreOS setup should enable you to view the webserver through the IP address of the host and the port you bound the container port on. 
However, since vagrant ports should be mapped too, you would have to map you 'real' hosts port, to the port on the host.

Steps to achieve an example:
1. Map port 80 of your localhost to your CoreOS vagrantboxes by providing this configuration in your Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
end
```

2. Run you container on CoreOS, and bind its exposing port to your CoreOS:

```
docker run --name containername \
    -p 80:80
    imagename /cmd
```

Now you should be able to reach your container by going to http://localhost in your browser.